# Which cryptocurrencies use the WIF format?

Tags: wallet-import-format

I know bitcoin uses Wallet Import Format. Do other crypto besides Bitcoin use WIF as a standard private key format?

Also, is the bitcoin private-to-public algorithm used by other crypto as a pretty common standard?

Answer (score 1):

> I know bitcoin uses Wallet Import Format. Do other crypto besides
> Bitcoin use WIF as a standard private key format?

The WIF represents the private key in Base58check encoded format. It is just a way to represent private key, nothing else. It is not part of Bitcoins network. We can't know how someone stores, encodes or works with their private keys. You can use WIF wherever you want.

> Also, is the bitcoin private-to-public algorithm used by other crypto
> as a pretty common standard?

Bitcoins private-to-public algorithm is based on elliptic curve multiplication. It is used in vast majority of cryptocurrencies.

Comment: As a follow-up to my WIF question, do a lot of wallets use WIF for cryptos other than bitcoin?

Comment: @Ed-K I would not say. It's not even used in Bitcoin that much anymore. Mostly today, private keys are based on the techniques of deriving one key from another. WIF was applied at the beginning when private keys were independently "made" and transmitted.